# Average extension method in Linq for default value

Tags: c#, .net, sql, linq, average

Anyone know how I can set a default value for an average? I have a line like this...

```
dbPlugins = (from p in dbPlugins
                select new { Plugin = p, AvgScore = p.DbVersions.Average(x => x.DbRatings.Average(y => y.Score)) })
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.AvgScore)
            .Select(x => x.Plugin).ToList();
```

which throws an error becase I have no ratings yet. If I have none I want the average to default to 0. I was thinking this should be an extension method where I could specify what the default value should be.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

There is: [`DefaultIfEmpty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360179.aspx).

I 'm not sure about what your `DbVersions` and `DbRatings` are and which collection exactly has zero items, but this is the idea:

```
var emptyCollection = new List<int>();
var average = emptyCollection.DefaultIfEmpty(0).Average();
```

**Update:** (repeating what's said in the comments below to increase visibility)

If you find yourself needing to use `DefaultIfEmpty` on a collection of class type, remember that you can change the LINQ query to project *before* aggregating. For example:

```
class Item
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

var list = new List<Item>();
var avg = list.Average(item => item.Value);
```

If you don't want to/can not construct a default `Item` with `Value` equal to 0, you can project to a collection of `int`s first and *then* supply a default:

```
var avg = list.Select(item => item.Value).DefaultIfEmpty(0).Average();
```

Comment: I don't think this is a good idea. Assume you have a `List<A>` and `A` is a class with a `int` property `Num`. You need to write the code like `listofA.DefaultItEmpty(defaultA).Average(a => a.Num)`. You need to construct a `defaultA` here.

Comment: @DannyChen: Not true: `listofA.Select(a => a.Num).DefaultIfEmpty(0).Average()`.

Comment: @Jon: But you went back to the start now, `x.DbRatings` can be null here. `p.DbVersions.Select(x => x.DbRatings).DefaultIfEmpty(defaultRatings)`, you need to specify the `defaultRatings`, it's not simply a number.

Comment: @DannyChen: Why on earth can `x.DbRatings` be `null`? I certainly expect it to be an empty `IQueryable<DbRating>` instead of `null`.

Comment: @DannyChen: `InvalidOperationException`. Please read the documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb354760.aspx

Answer (score 4):

My advice would to **create a reusable solution instead of a solution for this problem only.**

Make an extension method AverageOrDefault, similar to FirstOrDefault. See [extension methods demystified](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2013/03/08/c.net-little-wonders-extension-methods-demystified.aspx)

```
public static class MyEnumerableExtensions
{
    public static double AverageOrDefault(this IEnumerable<int> source)
    {
        // TODO: decide what to do if source equals null: exception or return default?
        if (source.Any())
            return source.Average();
        else
            return default(int);
    }
}
```

There are 9 overloads of Enumerable.Average, so you'll need to create an AverageOrDefault for double, int?, decimal, etc. They all look similar.

Usage:

```
// Get the average order total or default per customer
var averageOrderTotalPerCustomer = myDbContext.Customers
    .GroupJoin(myDbContext.Orders,
    customer => customer.Id,
    order => order.CustomerId,
    (customer, ordersOfThisCustomer) => new
    {
        Id = customer.Id,
        Name  = customer.Name,
        AverageOrder = ordersOfThisCustomer.AverageOrDefault(),
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way to select default, but how about this query

```
dbPlugins = (from p in dbPlugins
             select new { 
                Plugin = p, AvgScore = 
                    p.DbVersions.Any(x => x.DbRatings) ?
                        p.DbVersions.Average(x => x.DbRatings.Average(y => y.Score)) : 0 })
             .OrderByDescending(x => x.AvgScore)
             .Select(x => x.Plugin).ToList();
```

Essentially the same as yours, but we first ask if there are any ratings before averaging them. If not, we return 0.